# Inline contents of Element based on JS variable

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I would like to set innerHTML of element based on JS variable (when the page loads). For time being, I use

```
<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script>
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = myVar ? "Yes" : "No";
</script>
```

I would like to avoid the script tag. I'm thinking about

```
<div data-contents="myVar ? 'Yes' : 'No'"></div>
```

and then (after the page loads) handle elements with `data-contents` attribute, eval it and set the innerHTML to the result.

Is there a more afficient way, without scanning the DOM after the load? I use only client-side JS (no node-js) I do not want to create dependency on any JS library, ES6+ syntax is OK. Please avoid the cliché that eval is evil.